# Denoting the set of initial segments of a binary sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The index is an infinite, innumerable binary sequence in $\{0,1\}$. $ I= \{f \mid f: \Bbb {N} \to \{0,1\}\} $

Is there a way to get a set $X_i$ from the infinite index number $10110\ldots$

$ X_i = \{1,10,101,1011,10110,\ldots\}$ where $i \in I$ and $i=10110\ldots$

Comment: I have edited my post. Probably I should have added a bit more information to it from the beginning. The index is an infinite long binary sequence and contains only 0 and 1. Therefore the set will have an infinite size as well.

Comment: I basically would like to find a formula where I can transform an infinite index into a set. (See format above)

Comment: Do you mean a set of $0$-$1$ sequences, or a set of integers (interpreting the sequences in decimal, or binary)?

Comment: the result {1,10,101..} is a set of infinite binary sequences. As the index is infinite as well

Comment: You mean an infinite set of binary sequences, which is not the same thing. Each binary sequence in the set is itself finite.

Comment: sorry. Yes an infinite set of binary sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the elements of $X_f$ are supposed to be decimal numbers, then this would work:

$$X_f = \left\{\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)10^{n-i}\,\middle\vert\, n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$

If the elements of $X_f$ are supposed to be written in binary instead, replace the $10$ by a $2$.

---

**Added**: The $\sum$ notation denotes a sum. $f(i)$ is simply the $i$th element of your sequence. In this case, $$\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)10^{n-i} = f(0)10^n + f(1)10^{n-1}+\ldots+f(n)10^0$$

So for $n=0$, we have $f(0)10^0 = 1$. For $n=1$, we have $f(0)10^1+f(1)10^0 = 10+0=10$. For $n=2$, we arrive at $101$ (try it!).

The iteration variable $i$ is called the *index (variable)*. In this example, $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n$ means "sum the results of replacing $i$ by $0, 1,2,\ldots n$ in the expression on the right". A Google search on "sum notation" or "sigma notation" will likely help you further.

---

On the other hand, if you want $X_f$ to be the set of finite (non-empty) initial segments of $f$ (i.e. the sequences $(1), (1,0), (1,0,1)$ etc.) then this would work:

$$X_f = \left\{f \restriction_{\Bbb N_n}: \Bbb N_n \to \{0,1\} \,\middle\vert\, n \in \Bbb N\right\}$$

where $\Bbb N_n = \{0,1,\ldots n\}$ and $f\restriction_{\Bbb N_n}$ is the function obtained by restricting the domain of $f$ to $\Bbb N_n$.

Comment: Hi. I have difficulties to read the sigma sign. Could you explain how it would look like without sigma? (for the first 3 iteration) what does actually $f(i)$ do?

Comment: @Chris I've edited my answer to explain things in more detail.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation. That helped a lot. I will have to study your solution a bit more in depth. Will come back one I fully understood it.

Comment: Looking at your solution I can not see how that should work. The goal is to get a set of infinite amount of elements. The elements should be calculated from the index $i,j,k.. \in I$ . Lets say the index is 000 then the set would have 3 elements {0,00,000}. If the index is 1100 then the set would have 4 elements {1,11,110,1100}.

Comment: @Chris In your definition, the index cannot be $1100$, because it needs to be an infinite sequence (the domain of $f$ is all of $\Bbb N$). And while each element of the set uses only finitely many data of $f$, there is definitely an infinitude of elements in each $X_f$ (namely, an element for each $n \in \Bbb N$).

Comment: @Loard_Farin. True but I can also not show you an infinite index as an example :) Probably I have to look over your solution again.

Comment: Thanks. I finally understood it. And it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Chris Good to hear. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$${ X }_{ a }={ { \left\{ \left\lfloor \frac { a }{ { 10 }^{ n } }  \right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor \frac { a }{ { 10 }^{ n-1} }  \right\rfloor ,...,\left\lfloor \frac { a }{ { 10 }^{ 0 } }  \right\rfloor  \right\}  } }\\n=\left\lfloor \log _{ 10 }{ a }  \right\rfloor $$  This works for only finite sequences but you can divide the sequence and join. For example divide the total sequence such as $n=5$. The first five term would be $${ X }_{ a_{1-5} }={ { \left\{ \left\lfloor \frac { a_{1-5} }{ { 10 }^{ 5 } }  \right\rfloor ,\left\lfloor \frac { a_{1-5} }{ { 10 }^{ 4} }  \right\rfloor ,...,\left\lfloor \frac { a_{1-5} }{ { 10 }^{ 0 } }  \right\rfloor  \right\}  } }$$. The next $5$ term:

$${ X }_{ a_{6-10} }={ { \left\{ { X }_{ a_{1-5} }\left\lfloor \frac { a_{6-10} }{ { 10 }^{ 5 } }  \right\rfloor ,{ X }_{ a_{1-5} }\left\lfloor \frac { a_{6-10} }{ { 10 }^{ 4} }  \right\rfloor ,...,{ X }_{ a_{1-5} }\left\lfloor \frac { a_{6-10} }{ { 10 }^{ 0 } }  \right\rfloor  \right\}  } }$$.

This may not be very practical.

Comment: This works just for finite sequences.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting something like this?

$$X_n = \{x|x=\lfloor n10^{-a}\rfloor,a\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\}\setminus\{0\}$$

Comment: The edits by OP suggest that this is not what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The set of sequences can be written as
$$
  \{\, (f(i))_{i=1}^n\mid n\in\Bbb N_{>0}\,\},
$$
which is a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$, and is assumes you fixed an infinite sequece $f\in I$. If you want the empty sequence in your set as well, use $\Bbb N$ instead of $\Bbb N_{>0}$.